# Holonomy map on a connected manifold determines the connection and the bundle

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, connections, principal-bundles, holonomy

I am reading [Parallel transport on principal bundles over stacks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.05000). I quote from their paper :

> Let $G$ be a Lie group and $M$ a $C^{\infty}$ manifold. Recall that a
>   choice of a connection $1$-form $A\in \Omega^1(P,\mathfrak{g})^G$ on a
>   principal $G$-bundle $P$ over the manifold $M$ and a choice of base
>   point $x\in M$ gives rise to the holonomy map $$\Omega(M,x)\rightarrow
>  \text{Aut (fiber of $P$ at $x$)}\cong G,$$ where $\Omega(M,x)$ is the
>   set of smooth loops at $x$ in $M$.

I do not have a probelm with above set up, except that I do not know how they are identifying $\text{Aut (fiber of $P$ at $x$)}\cong G$. I think along with fixing a point $x\in M$, they are also fixing a point $u\in \pi^{-1}(x)$,  then, I know what is the map $\Omega(M,x)\rightarrow G$. If some one can clarify about it, it is good. But that is not the question. Question is from another line in the paper :

> For a connected manifold $M$ holonomy map uniquely determines the connection $A$, and infact the bundle $P$ itself.

The reference they gave is

> Shoshichi Kobayashi. La connexion des varietes fibrees. I, II. C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris, 238: 318–319, 443–444, 1954.

It is in a language that I can not read.

Can some one give an English reference where this is proved or a sketch of the proof is given or can some one write a sketch of the proof here?

Edit : As pointed in comments, there is an obvious way to identify $\text{Aut (fiber of $P$ at $x$)}\cong G$ if $G$ is abelian. In case $G$ is non abelian, can some one point me to a reference where this identification is explained.

Comment: The group of G-equivariant automorphism of a G-space with a free and transitive action is G itself, because any such automorphism is determined on any given point, and then given the original point and the point it is sent to, there is a unique element of G taking one to the other. Given any other starting point, it gives rise to the same group element. Moreover, composition of these automorphisms corresponds to group multiplication.

Comment: @DavidRoberts That is absolutely correct... I did not realise about the restriction of automorphism group to  equivariant automorphism group... So, there was some confusion.. As you said, if a Lie group $G$ acts freely, transitivley on a manifold $M$, the equivariant automorphism group is identified with the Lie group $G$... Here, $G$ acts on $\pi^{-1}(x)$ freely and transitively and the maps $\pi^{-1}(x)\rightarrow \pi^{-1}(x)$ are actually $G$-equivariant.. So, this is clear,,

Comment: If you're happy with uniqueness up to homotopy: By taking classifying spaces, the map $\Omega M \to G$ gives us a map $B(\Omega M) = M \to BG$, which is just the classifying map of the bundle, and so determines the bundle up to homotopy. Note that $B(\Omega M) = M$ requires $M$ connected.

Comment: Oh, ok.. I don’t know much about this  $B(\Omega(M)=M$.. I can not even convince myself that this is possible.. can you give so:e reference.. Assuming this, I got your point... Holonomy map is a map $\Omega(M,x)\rightarrow G$... See it as $\Omega(M)\rightarrow G$.. Then “take” the classifying space to get the map $M\rightarrow BG$.. then pullback the principal bundle $EG\rightarrow BG$ along this $M\rightarrow BG$ to get a principal bundle $P\rightarrow M$... what you said is mostly clear except that result..can you give some reference...

Comment: @DavidRoberts Is it not necessary for $G$ to be an abelian group? I see that the map $\phi:X\rightarrow X$ given by $\phi(x)=xg$ is not a $G$-equivariant map.. $\phi(x.h)=xgh\neq (xg).h=\phi(x).h$ unless $G$ is abelian.. Am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: Let $G$ be a Lie group, $X$ be a manifold.  Suppose further that $G$ acts freely and transitively on $X$. Let $\phi:X\rightarrow X$ be a $G$-equivariant diffeomorphism. Fix an element $x\in X$. Choose an element $y\in X$. As $G$ acts transitively on $X$, there exists $g\in G$ such that $y=x.g$. As $\phi$ is $G$-equivariant, $\phi(y)=\phi(x.g)=\phi(x).g$. Thus, $\phi(x)$ determines the map $\phi:X\rightarrow X$. So, any element of $X$ determines the map $\phi$.  Fix $x\in X$. We have $\phi(x)\in X$.  As $G$ acts freely and transitively, there exists **unique** $g\in G$ such that $\phi(x)=x.g$.

Comment: For another element $y\in X$ there exists **unique** $h\in G$ such that $\phi(y)=y.h$.  There exists unique $r\in G$ such that $y=x.r$. Then, $\phi(y)=\phi(x).r=x.g.r=yr^{-1}gr$. This conclude $r^{-1}gr=h$; that is $gr=rh$. Similarly, $\phi(x)=\phi(y)r^{-1}=yhr^{-1}=xrhr^{-1}$. So, we have $g=rhr^{-1}$; that is $gr=rh$. In case $G$ is abelian, I can then say $gr=hr$ which would then imply $g=h$. Thus, for each $\phi:X\rightarrow X$, there is unique $g\in G$ representing $\phi$...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I can answer that question, but not right now.

Comment: @DavidRoberts no problem. Please respond only when you are free

Answer (score 1):

See [Group of loops, holonomy maps, path bundle and path connection](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0264-9381/10/5/008/pdf)  by Jerzy Lewandowski and related [question on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/200812/connections-having-the-same-holonomy-along-loops-at-a-point).

Comment: Thank you. I do not have access to that article in my home. Once I go to my institute, I will check that and respond. thank you..